# Convert Json array into csv using apache Nifi

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, jsonpath

I'm looking to convert JSON with an array to csv format. The number of elements inside the array is dynamic for each row. I tried using this flow, ( attached the flow file xml on the post ).

GetFile --> ConvertRecord --> UpdateAttribute --> PutFile

Are there any other alternatives?

JSON format:

```
{  "LogData": {
"Location": "APAC",
"product": "w1"  },  "Outcome": [
{
  "limit": "0",
  "pri": "3",
  "result": "pass"
},
{
  "limit": "1",
  "pri": "2",
  "result": "pass"
},
{
  "limit": "5",
  "priority": "1",
  "result": "fail"
}  ],  "attr": {
"vers": "1",
"datetime": "2018-01-10 00:36:00"  }}
```

Expected output in csv:

```
location,   product,    limit,  pri,    result, vers,   datetime
APAC        w1          0       3       pass    1       2018-01-10 00:36:00
APAC        w1          1       2       pass    1       2018-01-10 00:36:00
APAC        w1          5       1       fail    1       2018-01-10 00:36:00
```

Output from the attached flow:
LogData,Outcome,attr
"MapRecord[{product=w1, Location=APAC}]","[MapRecord[{limit=0, result=pass, pri=3}], MapRecord[{limit=1, result=pass, pri=2}], MapRecord[{limit=5, result=fail}]]","MapRecord[{datetime=2018-01-10 00:36:00, vers=1}]"

[image]

ConvertRecord -- I am using JSONTreereader and CSVRecordSSetwriter configurations as below:
[image]

JSONTreereader Controler service config:
[image]
CSVRecordSetwriter controller service config:
[image]
AvroschemaRegistry Controller service config:
[image]

Avro schema :
    {  "name": "myschema",  "type": "record",  "namespace": "myschema",  "fields": [{"name": "LogData","type": {  "name": "LogData",  "type": "record",  "fields": [{  "name": "Location",  "type": "string"},{  "name": "product",  "type": "string"}  ]}},{"name": "Outcome","type": {  "type": "array",  "items": {"name": "Outcome_record","type": "record","fields": [  {"name": "limit","type": "string"  },  {"name": "pri","type": ["string","null"]  },  {"name": "result","type": "string"  }]  }}},{"name": "attr","type": {  "name": "attr",  "type": "record",  "fields": [{  "name": "vers",  "type": "string"},{  "name": "datetime",  "type": "string"}  ]}}  ]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this spec in JoltTransformJSON before ConvertRecord:

````
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Outcome": {
        "*": {
          "@(3,LogData.Location)": "[#2].location",
          "@(3,LogData.product)": "[#2].product",
          "@(3,attr.vers)": "[#2].vers",
          "@(3,attr.datetime)": "[#2].datetime",
          "*": "[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]```
````

Comment: Thanks a ton @mattyb for the help. This works like a charm. One question: If i have 1300 + array elements inside Outcome:[], will the jolt transform works well or will there be any overhead while converting 1 incoming json record to 1300+ json records?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by overhead, but I can tell you that all 1300+ flow files will be transferred at the same time, once they are all done processing and the session is committed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need to performa JoltTransform before convert to CSV, if not is not going to work.